# User Relationships and User Access Control

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

User Relationships works well to control node access to content per an approved user list.

But the problem I am running into is that I would like to also use the core Profile module, and allow those who are connected via User Relationships to see each others user profiles. I have spent 2 hours trying to figure out a way to not allow a user to spoof the URL and see any user account (Access User Profiles permission is required to see user profiles currently).

I thought of a couple solutions to fix this. What I want to do is serve a 403 page if the URL is spoofed and the requesting user has no access.

Here is what I was thinking:

1. Disable Access User Profile permission
2. Call hook_menu_alter or hook_menu_link_alter in a custom module
3. Change access callback to a custom function, check for user relationship
4. If no relationship exists serve a 403, otherwise return user_view

I wanted to get some thoughts on this, because I want this check to happen on the user profile page. hook_init() seemed too beefy.

Would this be an effective solution? Thoughts? Or is there a module that will allow me to do this quickly?

Comment: I think the hook_menu_alter or link_alter should do the trick perfectly well. Once you take control of those paths using those hooks, you can do anything you want, including checking for custom permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need: [CCK Private Fields](http://drupal.org/project/cck_private_fields) + [Content Profile](http://drupal.org/project/content_profile)

Comment: I don't want user accounts to become nodes though, added overhead of managing nodes which could just be a few profile fields in a user account.

Comment: In reality user accounts should be nodes. They basically are in 7. But I get it. My opinion is to try the existing solution before I code my own and just see how it does. That's what I'd recommend. Short of that, I'd override hook_user, $op=='view', and test for the relationship against the acting $user object. Then serve a 403 if need be. This approach lets you use all the data where it's going to be loaded anyway without doing any duplicate loading in a menu access callback.

Comment: Okay so assume I go back to Content Profile- how do you secure content with Views and Views paths so that access denied is served if said user should not see that users content? I'd like it to all just happen behind the scenes without the user having to utilize privacy controls. Right now I am using User Relationship to create a mutual relation, an implicit right to view content. I was hoping to use the UID from arg(1) but its been tricky.

Comment: All content on this site is private- similar to Facebook. Been trying to wrap my head around security so you can't just change the URL and see things you shouldn't.

Comment: Permisisons in views are pretty unsophisticated by default, but if any of the modules I recommended offer special permissions to the views access options, utilize them. Doing it by hand in hook_user, I don't know the user relationship API so without looking, I'd say look for a function that tells you if two users are related. Should be very simple. Again, I recommend you get in there and try it on a dev copy of the stie and see what all your options actually are with the modules enabled and configured.